# Mount and/or simulate volumes with existing directories?

Tags: mount, directory, disk, volume

I have lot of available space in `/home`

`df -h` output

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             8,9G  2,1G  6,4G  25% /
tmpfs                 499M  4,0K  499M   1% /dev/shm
/vol/home             2,7T  2,3T  403G  86% /home
```

Inside `/home/user/project` I have the following directories:

```
$ ls /home/user/project
log data bin
```

Is it possible to like "mount" this directories?

I want to achieve this:

```
$ df -h 
/dev/sda2             8,9G  2,1G  6,4G  25% /
tmpfs                 499M  4,0K  499M   1% /dev/shm
/vol/home             2,7T  2,3T  403G  86% /home
/vol/home/user        2,7T  2,3T  403G  86% /project/data
/vol/home/user        2,7T  2,3T  403G  86% /project/log
```

Comment: @roaima there's a project that uses `/project/log` and `/project/data` in its main configuration, but this are mounted volumes. This is my virtual machine so I can't mount this volumes in here, but I want to use and make some tests with that project. the thing is that my VM doesn't have available space but only in  `/home` volume

Comment: Do these need to be mounted filesystems, or is a place in the root filesystem referencing the space on `/home` matching this sufficient?

Comment: @roaima matching in the root path was enough. I didn't even try with symbolic link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symbolic link can be used to implement your filesystem map:

```
cd /
ln -s home/user/project
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mount --bind`. However, I don't believe it'll show up in `df -h`

```
mount --bind /vol/home /home
mount --bind /vol/home/user /project/data
mount --bind /vol/home /project/log
```

.

```
-B, --bind
          Remount a subtree somewhere  else  (so  that  its  contents  are
          available in both places).  See above.-
```

Comment: regarding "However, I don't believe it'll show up in df -h": AFAIK on Linux there is no difference between bind mounts and "real" mounts. But  df seems to de-duplicate the output. It will show randomly one mount point, either the first original one or the bind mount. See `/proc/self/mounts`, there is no special information about the bind mounts.